# When are parameters to vkCmd* functions consumed?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Some of the `vkCmd*` functions specify when some parameters are consumed or not. For example, in the documentation of `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets`:

> The contents of pDynamicOffsets are consumed immediately during
>   execution of vkCmdBindDescriptorSets.

However most of them do not clarify. Are all parameters consumed during the the `vkCmd*` call? For example, in the following code:

```
void copyHelper() {
  VkBufferCopy copy_region = {...};
  vkCmdCopyBuffer(cmd_buffer, from_buffer, to_buffer, 1, &copy_region);
}
```

after calling `copyHelper()`, `copy_region` is not in scope anymore although `cmd_buffer` hasn't been submitted yet. Do I need to store `copy_region` somewhere so that it stays valid? Or is it immediately consumed when calling `vkCmdCopyBuffer`? What about the rest of the `vkCmd*` functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no per-command clarification, because all commands operate under the following blanket statement:

> The ownership of application-owned memory is immediately acquired by any Vulkan command it is passed into. Ownership of such memory **must** be released back to the application at the end of the duration of the command, so that the application **can** alter or free this memory as soon as all the commands that acquired it have returned.

Emphasis in the specification. The implementation has to be finished using the contents of any memory you pass by the time the function returns. Whether unformatted memory like a `void*` or data structures.

Note that "duration" is defined as:

> The *duration* of a Vulkan command refers to the interval between calling the command and its return to the caller.

Comment: And that's important in multithreading. Don't let another thread mess with memory that you passed into a function.

Comment: @ZanLynx Which is further clarified in the 2.6. Threading Behavior: "Similarly the application **must** avoid any potential data hazard of application-owned memory that has its _ownership temporarily acquired_ by a Vulkan command. While the ownership of application-owned memory remains acquired by a command the implementation **may** read the memory at any point, and it **may** write non-`const` qualified memory at any point. Parameters referring to non-`const` qualified application-owned memory are not marked explicitly as _externally synchronized_ in the Specification."